# Worst case running time BFS

Tags: time-complexity, breadth-first-search

I am confused with BFS complexity. Wikipédia say : "The time complexity can be expressed as O(|V|+|E|) since every vertex and every edge will be explored in the worst case".

```
set start vertex to visited

load it into queue

while queue not empty

    for each edge incident to vertex

         if its not visited

             load into queue

             mark vertex
```

For me the worst case is : each vertex are connected to all the vertices
So the while loop will be done V times and the for loop E times. A worst case scenario of 0(VE).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: E is all edges in the graph. So in your example, |E| = |V| * (|V| - 1).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of BFS is to visit all the nodes once. No vertex ever gets into the queue for a second time (which explains the |V|). The |E| of the summation comes from the assumption that checking incident edges costs nothing compared to a visit. So yes, for a complete graph (all vertices are connected to all other vertices) VE edges will be checked...but checking them does not cost a visit.

Comment: I agree with you that a visit cost "more" than a checking. But this annoy me, for me when we speak complexity we shouldn't look at if visit > check. Strictly speaking checking is O(1) and checking + visit is also O(1). It is like we don't take into account all the iteration where the checking is false. If it is the case, this kind of assumption should be precise somewhere.
Anyway, thanks for your answer ;).

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity of BFS is O(|V|+|E|). V is the number of total vertex and E is the number of total edge. You may mistake for the E. E is not the neighbor edges of vertex u.

We can implement this as below.

for each u in vertices

for each e in neighbor(u)

```
do something.
```

Comment: In your second loop : "for each e in neighbor(u)", if the neighbor of u are all the vertices (in the case of all vertices are connected to all other vertices). Aren't we in O(VE)?

Comment: E is the number of total edge in that graph. E is not the number of edges with a vertex in a graph. So, O(VE) means that a vertex connected with other vertex with total edges. It is wrong.

Comment: When we visit a vertex, we do not have to check all the edges. We just check the neighbor edges of vertex.